# Iterate in Jmeter wrt two columns of CSV/excel

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have an extenal test data file (excel/csv).

[image: extenal test data file]

My requirement is In my jmx tree my first http request should take the value from **ContentName** column, ex: **www.sample.${ContentName}** and to that i need to apply 
**JsonPathExtractorApi** column as **jp@gc - JSON Path extractor**.

Please not that i need to have only one json path extractor which takes **${JsonPathExtractorApi}**. where for Hotel i need to extract 4 times where as for ship 2 times, for Gem 3 times as the number of  JsonPathExtractorApi against that.

Below i have attached the sample which im trying to implement.

[image: SampleJMX file]

Problems :
1.How can find the total number of **JsonPathExtractorApi** against each **ContentName**.

2.If i keep my CSV outside the loop controller i cant traverse through csv ,every time i get first value(ContentName).

3.If i keep csv inside loop,i can traverse through csv but cant take the contentvalue before it(for the first http sampler where i have to take response data)

Please can anyone take time and suggest on this.Any other approach is also acceptable if it serve the purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any control of this "external data file" the only solution would be going for 2 [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) instances

Example [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) outline:

- [Test Fragment](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment)

  - What do you have under the Loop Controller
- Thread Group

  - CSV Data Set Config
  - If Controller, condition: `${__groovy(!vars.get('ContentName').equals(''),)}`

    - HTTP Request - Content Name
    - [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) - point to the Test Fragment
  - If Controller, condition: `${__groovy(vars.get('ContentName').equals(''),)}`

    - Module Controller - point to the Test Fragment

Demo:

[image: JMeter Demo Test Plan for If Controller and Module Controller]